# Why Geometry's Tangent are difference from Tangent node?

Tags: node-editor, normals

According to the [document](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html), geometry node's tangent is surface tangent in world space. And tangent node is [from a manually created UV Map for full control when use UVMap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/tangent.html). They output difference result to me.
[image: Geometry node output]
[image: Tangent node output]
In my understanding, tangent inherently associated with uv, so the tangent node output result is right. I just wonder what exactly is the geometry's tangent to. Can anyone explaning it to me? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per your link:

> **Direction Type**
>
> The tangent direction can be derived from a cylindrical projection
> around the X, Y, or Z axis (radial), **or** from a manually created UV
> Map for full control.

*Geometry -> Tangent* is giving you the same output as the *Tangent* node set to Radial Z.

[image]

Comment: Nicely illustrated